# How to make UIPageviewcontroller like a slide image viewer

Tags: swift, swift4

I had used the UIPageViewController. This type of Controller will take up the entire Page Of VC to display with the 3 dots at the bottom.
I have been searching on internet for customize UIPageViewController with no success.
This is my problem:
in a VC:
1) Display UIPageViewController at the Top so there is space to display other UI in the middle and bottom of VC.

How to display UIPageViewController in a fixed size,say, 320 x 240 with 3 dots (indicators) immediately below the display image in a VC?

Thanks

Comment: SO it's not a code service. Please provide some code that you have tried and we will help you. We are not a code service.

Answer (score 0):

To put a UIPageViewController's view anywhere you like in the interface, make it an embedded view controller. In other words, you have a parent view controller and a child view controller, where the page view controller is the child. There are strict rules about how to implement a custom parent-child relationship, but if you do it according to the rules, the frame of the page view controller's view is then completely up to you.

Comment: Actual downloadable example project here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p317pageControllerChild/ch19p626pageController/RootViewController.swift